# showing blank screen on back button android

Tags: android

How can I avoid showing blank screen after user click Back button of device in the authentication step?

*[ Edited]*

The flow is user is asked to authenticate via twitter.
If the user reaches the step, it is possible that user doesn't authenticate and press the back button of device and return to the app. At that step, the app show blank page.

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                if (MyUtils.checkIsAuthenticated(prefs)) {
                    //sending the tweet
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context,
                            GotoRequestTokenActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How about disable the back button?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the onBackPressed() method ,you can do something there to disable the back button pr finishing your activity or display a relevant toast like "cancelling the authentication"

Answer (score 0):

Your qsn is, from dialog, instead of pressing button on dialog user presses back key? or is it after you move to launched activity and user presses back?

in first case, i guess you shall check if user is bypassing dialog in OnResume. 
in 2nd case, make your dialog an activity with dialog theme and call finish() in onclicklistener. (ur dialog shall dismiss when you go to next activity)

In any case, check ur log and see if you leaking something.

Answer (score 0):

you use this demo for twitter integration because this demo opens a dialog for login instead of open the twitter url for login...so, if you want to back from that you can easily do that..see this link...This is just like facebook dialog..

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitter